# Декодирование JPEG

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

Подскажите свободно распространяемую библиотеку (совместимую с Windows) или исходник, в котором из JPEG файла выделялись квантованные косинусные коэффициенты. Это первый шаг обратного JPEG-декодирования (коды Huffman-а в DCT-коэффициенты). Я знаю алгоритм как это сделать, но очень не хочется заново изобретать велосипед и тратить время на тестирование самопальной программы.

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, зачем?

Comment: Есть кое-какие идеи относительно применения ИИ для анализа изображений, где используется частотное представление (даже квантованное). Больше пока не скажу :).

Comment: На libjpeg смотрели? [Extracting JPEG DCT coefficients](https://aessedai101.github.io/c++/jpeg/jpg/dct/libjpeg/2014/07/10/extracting-jpeg-dct-coefficients.html)

Comment: Да, но бегло.  По первому взгляду там все решается крупными блоками без промежуточных шагов, хотя я мог конечно не заметить. Сейчас читаю к ней "доку"

Comment: @zed - пока писал ответ, Вы уже подсказали огромное спасибо. То что нужно.

Comment: @zed - пожалуйста оформите, свой комментарий как ответ, чтобы я мог добавить Вам баллов и пометить свой вопрос, как решенный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью libjpeg.

Пример (отсюда: [Extracting JPEG DCT coefficients](https://aessedai101.github.io/c++/jpeg/jpg/dct/libjpeg/2014/07/10/extracting-jpeg-dct-coefficients.html)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jpeglib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

JBLOCKARRAY rowPtrs[MAX_COMPONENTS];

void read(jpeg_decompress_struct srcinfo, jvirt_barray_ptr * src_coef_arrays) {
    //cout << "Started reading DCT" << endl;
    for (JDIMENSION compNum=0; compNum < srcinfo.num_components; compNum++) {
        size_t blockRowSize = (size_t) sizeof(JCOEF) * DCTSIZE2 * srcinfo.comp_info[compNum].width_in_blocks;
        for (JDIMENSION rowNum=0; rowNum < srcinfo.comp_info[compNum].height_in_blocks; rowNum++) {
            // A pointer to the virtual array of dct values
            rowPtrs[compNum] = ((&srcinfo)->mem->access_virt_barray)((j_common_ptr) &srcinfo, src_coef_arrays[compNum],rowNum, (JDIMENSION) 1, FALSE);
            // Loop through the blocks to get the dct values
            for (JDIMENSION blockNum=0; blockNum < srcinfo.comp_info[compNum].width_in_blocks; blockNum++){
                //...iterate over DCT coefficients
                for (JDIMENSION i=0; i<DCTSIZE2; i++){
                    //and print them to standard out - one per line
                    cout << rowPtrs[compNum][0][blockNum][i] << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
  //TODO: change this to read a different file
  const char* filename = "image4.jpg";

  FILE * infile;  
  struct jpeg_decompress_struct srcinfo;
  struct jpeg_error_mgr srcerr;

  if ((infile = fopen(filename, "rb")) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "can't open %s\n", filename);
    return 0;
  }

  srcinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&srcerr);
  jpeg_create_decompress(&srcinfo);
  jpeg_stdio_src(&srcinfo, infile);
  (void) jpeg_read_header(&srcinfo, FALSE);

  //coefficients
  jvirt_barray_ptr * src_coef_arrays = jpeg_read_coefficients(&srcinfo);
  read(srcinfo, src_coef_arrays);

  jpeg_destroy_decompress(&srcinfo);
  fclose(infile);
  return 0; 
}
```